# R limit decimal places in View() tables

Tags: r, format, decimal

I would like to limit the number of decimals in tables displayed by the View() function. I tried options(digits=2) but it seems not to be a good choice. Thank you in advance.

Upd. Closed.

I tested options() for my table which anyway returned more than 2 decimal places. The problem was in the table - numeric values were converted to characters and I was unaware of this. Other tables now show just expected decimal places.

So, options() is a good choice, but it is necessary to check out the data types.

Comment: `options(digits = 2)` should show you only two decimal places. Why is it not a good choice? What is your expected outcome?

Comment: Right. I tested options() for my table which anyway returned more than 2 decimal places. The problem was in the table - numeric values were converted to characters and I was unaware of this. Other tables now show just expected decimal places.

So, options() is a good choice, but it is necessary to check out the data types.

Answer (score 0):

In case you only want to change the behaviour of `View`, rather than changing the options globally, you could write a function to provide this:

```
View.2 = function(x, digits=2) {
  title = as.character(substitute(x))
  x = data.frame(lapply(x, function(y) if(is.numeric(y)) round(y, digits) else y)) 
  View(x, title)
}

View.2(iris)
```